# Time Interval Formatting

Tags: ios, swift, time, localization, date-formatting

I am looking to display a time interval from an audio clip i.e.:
`"Snippet A is from 0:20 - 0:24"`

I have tried to use `DateIntervalFormatter` like so:

```swift
let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .short
formatter.dateStyle = .none

let interval = DateInterval(start: .init(), duration: 20)
let (_start, _end) = (interval.start, interval.end)
let getTimeComponents = {
    Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .second], from: $0)
}
let startComponents = getTimeComponents(_start)
let endComponents = getTimeComponents(_end)

let dateFrom = { Calendar.current.date(from: $0) }
let start = dateFrom(startComponents)!
let end = dateFrom(endComponents)!
let string = formatter.string(from: start, to: end)
print(string) // OUTPUT: "12:34 – 12:35 AM"
```

But does not format in the desired way. I've looked at `DateComponentsFormatter` and `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`, but they don't appear to provide the desired behaviour either.

Is there a `Formatter` in Foundation that provides this behaviour? Implementing this manually seems prone to error when considering localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the thing you are formatting represents a number of minutes and seconds, as opposed to a time of the day or a date, you should use `DateComponentsFormatter`.

You can first format the timestamps, then use string interpolation to include the rest of the sentence:

```
let start: TimeInterval = 20
let end: TimeInterval = 24

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
let startString = formatter.string(from: start)
let endString = formatter.string(from: end)
let result = "Snippet A is from \(startString) - \(endString)"
```

You *could* also "cheat" and use `DateIntervalFormatter`... You just need to set `dateTemplate` to the desired format.

```
let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
formatter.dateTemplate = "m:ss"
let intervalString = formatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: start), to: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: end))
let result = "Snippet A is from \(intervalString)"
```

I feel like this is a cheat because you are not actually formatting dates. If you have a 24-hour-long audio clip, and the timestamp 24:00:00, `DateIntervalFormatter` won't be able to format it, but `DateComponentsFormatter` *will*. That said, there is not actually a `TimestampIntervalFormatter`...

Comment: I've considered this, but was concerned around localization for the A-B part. I suppose the whole string would need to be localized either way though.

Comment: @jjatie Okay, so you were worried about the "-" part... See the edit.